# ERROR! - Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

I've looked around but I can not find anything to help me in my case.

I am using SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CommodityCode.CommodityCode AS ComCode, 
Facility.FacilityAcctNum, 
Vessel.VesselType, 
Facility.FacilityNm, 
 Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End AS RecF,

     Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'D' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End AS RecD,

     Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'S' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'D' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End AS Shipped,

     Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'S' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End AS ShippedF,
Commodities.Destination,
Commodities.Origin, 
Commodities.Specific, 
CommodityCode.Descr, 
Facility.FacilityID, 
TransactionCharge.ArrivalDt, 
TransactionCharge.DepartDt, 
TransactionCharge.DtDocked, 
TransactionCharge.DtSailed

FROM Vessel 
INNER JOIN Commodities 
INNER JOIN CommodityCode ON Commodities.CommodityCode = CommodityCode.CommodityCode 
INNER JOIN TransactionCharge ON Commodities.TransactionID = TransactionCharge.TransactionID ON Vessel.VesselID = TransactionCharge.VesselId 
INNER JOIN Facility ON TransactionCharge.FacilityID = Facility.FacilityID 
INNER JOIN Unit ON Commodities.Unit = Unit.Unit 
INNER JOIN TransactionFee ON TransactionCharge.TransactionID = TransactionFee.TransactionID

GROUP BY 
CommodityCode.CommodityCode, 
Facility.FacilityAcctNum, 
Vessel.VesselType, 
Facility.FacilityNm, 
Commodities.Destination, 
Commodities.Origin, 
Commodities.Specific, 
CommodityCode.Descr, 
Facility.FacilityID, 
Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
         )
         End
      Else 0
      End,

     Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'D' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End,

     Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'S' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'D' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End,

     Case
      When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'S' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' Then
     Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
        Else
        Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
              Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
        Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
              Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
          )
         End
      Else 0
      End,
TransactionCharge.ArrivalDt, 
TransactionCharge.DepartDt, 
TransactionCharge.DtDocked, 
TransactionCharge.DtSailed

HAVING (Vessel.VesselType='V' Or Vessel.VesselType='O')
```

Comment: Why are you GROUPing in the first place as you seem to have no aggregates (SUM, MAX, COUNT, etc.) in your query?  You also have a DISTINCT which seems to serve no purpose.  If you remove the GROUP BY clause and change the HAVING to a WHERE does it work as intended?

Comment: The Query runs but does not return the intended data.

Comment: It seems to me that if you did manage to get this to work using GROUP BY (either by using a subquery or a common-table expression for example) then it would return EXACTLY THE SAME DATA.  Seeing as this isn't what you intended then maybe the problem is somewhere else in your query?  I can see a LOT of things wrong with that query in any case, for example how does the INNER JOIN to Commodities work as it has no ON clause?  Another example, why do you have a subquery to lookup values from the Unit table when this table is already in the main body of the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have subqueries in your case statement in your `GROUP BY`. For example, looking at the first part of the case statement:

```
When Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' And Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' Then
 Case When Commodities.Amount Is Null Or Commodities.Unit Is Null Then Null
    Else
    Round (Commodities.Amount/Case When Commodities.Unit = 'B' Then (Select BushelFactor From CommodityCode
          Where CommodityCode.CommodityCode = Commodities.CommodityCode)
    Else (Select ShortTonFactor From Unit
          Where Unit.Unit = Commodities.Unit) End,2
     )
     End
  Else 0
  End,
```

There are two there to start with, beginning with `Select BushelFactor...` and `Select ShortTonFactor...`, so you will have to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick go at reformatting your query and removing/ commenting some of the issues with it:

```
SELECT --DISTINCT - do you really want DISTINCT?
    cc.CommodityCode AS ComCode, 
    f.FacilityAcctNum, 
    v.VesselType, 
    f.FacilityNm, 
    CASE
        WHEN Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' AND Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN Commodities.Amount IS NULL OR Commodities.Unit IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE ROUND(Commodities.Amount /
                CASE 
                    WHEN Commodities.Unit = 'B' THEN cc.BushelFactor
                    ELSE u.ShortTonFactor 
                END, 2)
        END
        ELSE 0
    END AS RecF,
    CASE
        WHEN Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'R' AND Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'D' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN Commodities.Amount IS NULL OR Commodities.Unit IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE
            ROUND(Commodities.Amount /
                CASE 
                    WHEN Commodities.Unit = 'B' THEN cc.BushelFactor
                    ELSE u.ShortTonFactor END, 2)
        END
        ELSE 0
    END AS RecD,
    CASE
        WHEN Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'S' AND Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'D' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN Commodities.Amount IS NULL OR Commodities.Unit IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE
            ROUND(Commodities.Amount / 
                CASE 
                    WHEN Commodities.Unit = 'B' THEN cc.BushelFactor
                    ELSE u.ShortTonFactor
                END, 2)
        END
        ELSE 0
    END AS Shipped,
    CASE
        WHEN Commodities.ShippedReceivedId = 'S' AND Commodities.ForeignDomesticId = 'F' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN Commodities.Amount IS NULL OR Commodities.Unit IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE
            ROUND(Commodities.Amount/ 
                CASE 
                    WHEN Commodities.Unit = 'B' THEN cc.BushelFactor
                    ELSE u.ShortTonFactor
                END, 2)
        END
        ELSE 0
    END AS ShippedF,
    c.Destination,
    c.Origin, 
    c.Specific, 
    cc.Descr, 
    f.FacilityID, 
    tc.ArrivalDt, 
    tc.DepartDt, 
    tc.DtDocked, 
    tc.DtSailed
FROM 
    Vessel v
    INNER JOIN Commodities c ON --some_condtion, OR is this a cross join?
    INNER JOIN CommodityCode cc ON c.CommodityCode = cc.CommodityCode 
    INNER JOIN TransactionCharge tc ON c.TransactionID = tc.TransactionID AND v.VesselID = tc.VesselId 
    INNER JOIN Facility f ON tc.FacilityID = f.FacilityID 
    INNER JOIN Unit u ON c.Unit = u.Unit 
    INNER JOIN TransactionFee td ON tc.TransactionID = tf.TransactionID
WHERE
    v.VesselType IN ('V', 'O');
```

I don't expect this to produce the answers you want, but it might make it easier to spot what is wrong with your original query now that the logic is somewhat simplified?